# Prevent Other Outlook Recipients from Forwarding, Printing, or Copying Content from Your Message?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook-2010

If you are sending out an email message to a contact and prefer that it isn’t forwarded to someone else, printed, or any of the content copied, Outlook 2010 allows you to do this, but I don't know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Rights_Management) is the feature in Outlook (since 2007) that has supported the features you describe. It relies on having access to an [RMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rights_Management_Services) server, typically a Windows Server machine (Rights Management Services have been around since Windows Server 2003).

In Outlook 2010, IRM operates through an [Exchange server](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/en/us/information-protection-and-control.aspx), although any RMS-supporting mail client should be able to receive the mails, as long as it has LAN/WAN/Internet access to the RMS server that manages the rights.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/outlook/archive/2008/06/17/irm-in-outlook-2007.aspx) is an overview of exactly how it works. The examples are based on Outlook 2007, but the principle will be the same in 2010.

Comment: Please highlight the need for RMS and Exchange server. This feature is not enable on a Single User home installation!